# Add tabs to TabControl from another form

Tags: c#, vb.net, forms, tabs

This is freaking me out, and if this is possible I would gladly appreciate the help.

I am a C# developer but have to do this in VB.NET.

So C# answers accepted as well.

- I have a tab control on a form. This control does not have any tabs in it yet.
- When the form loads, it loads a "Start" page. It adds the tab "tbpStart" and loads a form onto the tab page "frmStart".
- On this start page, I have many Radio Buttons. When I click on one radio button, it should load other tabs on the main form.

The problem is how can I add tabs to one form's tab control from another form?

CODE:

When Main Form loads:

```
Try
    'Load the Start Tab
    Dim start As New frmTabStart
    AddTabPage("Start", start)
Catch ex As Exception
    PMComponentLibrary.PMMessageBox.ShowErrorMessage("Error occurred while trying to load the from.", ex)
End Try
```

Function on Main Form:

```
Public Sub AddTabPage(tabPageName As String, myForm As System.Windows.Forms.Form)
    Try
        myForm.TopLevel = False
        myForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        myForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None

        Dim NewTab As New System.Windows.Forms.TabPage
        NewTab.Name = "tab" + tabPageName
        NewTab.Text = tabPageName
        NewTab.Controls.Add(myForm)
        tbcMain.TabPages.Add(NewTab)
        myForm.Show()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

When I click on one Radio Button on "Start Form" it executes this on a click_event:

```
If sender Is rdbWIPPostings Then

    entity = New frmTabEntity()
    mainForm.AddTabPage("Step 1", entity)
    Application.DoEvents()
    dte = New frmTabDate()
    mainForm.AddTabPage("Step 2", dte)

    wipSelect = New frmTabWIPSelect()
    mainForm.AddTabPage("Step 3", wipSelect)

    finish = New frmTabFinish()
    mainForm.AddTabPage("Finish", finish)

End If
```

But the tabs does not get added to the Main Form.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get `mainForm` here?

Comment: mainForm is the instance of the parent form which is on the child form.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. How did you set `mainForm`? Was it injected into the constructor of the child form with `this`?

Comment: Are you passing mainForm as byRef on the Startform contructor? Or are you getting mainForm from a different place. My guess is the mainform reference is different from the reference you see on the screen.

Comment: The problem is not on MainForm. The form is shown. On its Load_Event, it calls my first code block. MainForm also contains the second code block which is a void function(Sub). this adds the tab on load and it also adds the Startup form to the new tab. THIS works. problem is on the form that was added as a control to the tab page... from this child form I want to add more tabs to the MainForm.

Comment: On the child form (frmStart) I instantiate MainForm to be able to call its method: AddTabPage().                      Mainform is instantiated like this on frmStart: Private mainForm As New frmReportWizardNew()

Comment: @FrederikMoller Are you saying then that frmStart starts before mainForm? Or it is the other way around?

Comment: Its the other way around. MainForm is loaded first. its a normal showdialog. on the load event of main form, as you can see, it calls the method AddTabPage and there it adds and instantiates the frmStartup. I want to add more tabs from frmStartup which should appear on MainForm. frmStartup is already in a tab on MainForm at this point.

Comment: could you upload the sample project somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the constructor for `frmTabStart` to receive an instance of `mainForm` like this:

```
public frmTabStart(MainForm mainForm)
{
    // store that in a field
}
```

and then when you need to add the tab:

```
_mainForm.AddTabPage(...);
```

Comment: This was the fix... sad I did not try this first... thank you @Neoistheone

Comment: @FrederikMoller, not a problem! I'm glad I could be of assistance!