# Adding a tabPage to a separate Form

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tabcontrol

I have 2 forms, one is labelled Form1.cs and it has a tabControl with 2 tabs in it as default. I have Form2.cs which has a label (Name:), a textbox and an "OK" button on it.

I am looking to create a new tab on Form1.cs with the name at the top of the tab being whatever is typed into the textbox.

I am very new to C# / Visual Studio and finding it hard to read up anything that might be able to assist me with this.

Form1.cs and Form2.cs

```
namespace Scoreboard3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void scoreboard2pToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace Scoreboard3
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public string SelectedText { get; set; }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void txtBox2v2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.TabControl1.TabPages.Add;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to [post some of your Form code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/) for us to understand what you have. What are you having trouble doing? Creating a new tab? Changing the tab name? Typing something in a textbox? [Restrict your question to one problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion).

Comment: Get some ideas from [Add tabs to TabControl from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726416/add-tabs-to-tabcontrol-from-another-form) and [Adding tabpage to a tabcontrol which is on another form on click of button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768348/adding-tabpage-to-a-tabcontrol-which-is-on-another-form-on-click-of-button) and [access tab control for other form in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32568300/access-tab-control-for-other-form-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @DourHighArch 

I have posted the code from Form1 and Form2

I want to type something into the textbox (example, "CSGO") and when I press OK, it will produce a new tab in Form1 which would say CSGO in the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to access that tab control from another form. You can do:

In the first form that contains the tab control:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void scoreboard2pToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Form2 f2 = new Form2())
        {
            if(f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                TabControl1.TabPages.Add(f2.SelectedText);
                //or insert
                //TabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, f2.SelectedText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second form:

```cs
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    //A read only property to return the text entered in the text box.
    public string SelectedText => txtBox2v2.Text;

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //You only need to do this in your OK button.
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Let each form deals with its own contents.